# Dozen, hundred, thousand vs dozens, hundreds, thousands

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns, syntax, numbers

I have read that dozen, hundred, thousand etc. have no -s and of when they are used after a numerical, a few or several :
Three dozen eggs.
A few hundred times,
Several thousand years.
But with some and many, they take -s, and of is used :
Some/many dozens of mangoes.

There are some similar questions in this form but they don't clarify the following, particularly my 2nd question.

1. "Three dozen eggs" is correct; but "three dozen of eggs" is not correct. Why?
2. "Some/many dozens of eggs" is correct; but "A few/several dozens of eggs" is incorrect.

Why? I am really confused. Could anyone of you please clarify my queries with brief & precise grammatical explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Four dozen" or "Four dozens"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71408/four-dozen-or-four-dozens)

Comment: In #2, I would not say that "some/many dozens of eggs" is correct. Understandable, but does not sound natural.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no plural 's' after "hundred" or "thousand" in cardinal numbers?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38635/why-is-there-no-plural-s-after-hundred-or-thousand-in-cardinal-numbers)

Comment: Why is it wrong to say "A few/Several dozens of mangoes"?

Comment: 'Some/Many dozens of mangoes" --is it correct or not? Why?

Comment: Your called out question in the second paragraph is misleading. Neither *three **dozen** of eggs* **nor** *three **dozens** of eggs* is grammatical. You also seem to be asking several different questions. Or at least it's not clear what specific question you are asking. I would focus on a single thing with a single example.

Answer (score 3):

Collins Dictionary says: *The plural form is dozen after a number, or after a word or expression referring to a number, such as 'several' or 'a few'*.

We usually use *dozen* without *of* unless the 12 items are being selected from a particular group - *a dozen eggs*, but *a dozen of your freshest eggs*. There's no use asking why; that's just the way it is.

We say *dozens of* meaning a lot. I think *many dozens of mangoes* implies an indeterminate number, but for a specific number we would say *ten dozen mangoes.*

Comment: Thank you, @Kate Bunting.  Your valuable opinion is appreciated.